# How can I remove these white bars from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have these white bars on the bottom and side of my Eclipse editor:

[image]

How can I remove them?

FYI, I installed Moonrise theme and some dark color scheme.

Comment: Pretty sure that those are scroll bars

Comment: I resized the window and yes you are right! They are the background color of the scroll bar. Can I change the color of it though?

Comment: Not sure how to color the scrollbar, but [this](http://superuser.com/questions/428118/hide-scrollbars-in-eclipse-editors) might help you hide the scrollbar. The second answer contains instructions for mac.